# How to update table based on another table in EntityFramework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, t-sql

I have this `StationStateItem` table with this data:

```
Id  SSHdrRef      Amount  
---------------------------
1   1(forrein Key)   1
2   1                1
3   2                2
4   2                2
5   3                1
```

I want to update `StationStateHdr` table when amount changed in `StationStateItem`.

```
BeforeSSAmount=StationStateHdr.StationStateItem.Sum(x=> x.Amount)
```

`StationStateHdr` Table like this :

```
Id  BeforeSSAmount
--------------
1   0 
2   2 (1+1)
3   6 (1+1+2+2)
```

Comment: you should try first...you're always asking questions and answering none.

Comment: You want to update both tables right..?? manually do it. Or atleast Show us your object classes for these.. Also show the function where you update Table StationStateItem

Comment: I like to update BeforeSSAmount in StationStateHdr table, when I change Amout in StationStateItem Table and  click Save Button.

Answer (score 2):

Try Code

```
  foreach(var a in StationStateHdr)
   {
     a .BeforeSSAmount=StationStateHdr.StationStateItem.where(c=>c.SSHdrRef<a.id).Sum(x=> x.Amount)
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code :

```
var afters = ctx.headers.SkipWhile(((x, index) => index <= currentItemIndex))
                .TakeWhile((x, index) => index != ctx.headers.Count()-1).ToList();

            for (int i = currentItemIndex+1, j=0; j < afters.Count; i++ ,j++)
            {
                var befores = ctx.headers.TakeWhile((x, index) => index <i);
                afters[j].BeforeSSAmount = befores.SelectMany(x => x.StationStateItem).Sum(x => x.Amount);
            }
```

Edited for use ListCollectionView in wpf:

```
  var afters = header.DataSource.Cast<StationStateHdr>().SkipWhile(((x, index) => index <= header.DataSource.CurrentPosition))
        .TakeWhile((x, index) => index != header.DataSource.Cast<StationStateHdr>().Count()-1).ToList();

    for (int i = header.DataSource.CurrentPosition+1, j=0; j < afters.Count; i++ ,j++)
    {
        var befores = header.DataSource.Cast<StationStateHdr>().TakeWhile((x, index) => index <i);
        afters[j].BeforeSSAmount = befores.SelectMany(x => x.StationStateItem).Sum(x => x.Amount);
    }
```

or this Code :

```
    var listOfStationStateHdr = header.DataSource.Cast<StationStateHdr>();
    listOfStationStateHdr.SkipWhile(((x, index) => index <= header.DataSource.CurrentPosition))
        .TakeWhile((x, index) => index != header.DataSource.Cast<StationStateHdr>().Count() - 1).ToList().ForEach(x =>
    {
        x.BeforeSSAmount = listOfStationStateHdr.TakeWhile(y => y.Id < x.Id).SelectMany(b => b.StationStateItem).Sum(s => s.Amount);
    });
```

or

```
    var sumCurrent = CurrentStationStateHdr.StationStateItem.Sum(t => t.Amount);
    var listOfStationStateHdr = header.DataSource.Cast<StationStateHdr>().ToList();
    double? nextItembeforeSSAmount = listOfStationStateHdr[header.DataSource.CurrentPosition + 1].BeforeSSAmount;

    listOfStationStateHdr.SkipWhile(((x, index) => index <= header.DataSource.CurrentPosition))
        .TakeWhile((x, index) => index != header.DataSource.Cast<StationStateHdr>().Count() - 1).ToList().ForEach(x =>
        {
            x.BeforeSSAmount += sumCurrent - nextItembeforeSSAmount;
        });
```

Comment: thanks for your help but, what is currentItemIndex ?

Comment: I have custom WPF DataGridNavigator Control, it has DataSource Property that is ListCollectionView.

Comment: so currentItemIndex is header.DataSource.CurrentPosition